# SQL Update Function x 6 in the same query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tried several iterations of this basic idea, including using case statements without success.  I'm wondering if it's even possible to change the same column in a database multiple times in one query.  I keep getting a syntax error...  Any ideas?

```
UPDATE [DATA GROUP]
    SET [DATA GROUP].[Type]="E"
    WHERE [DATA GROUP].[Name] Like "EMI*" 

UPDATE [DATA GROUP] 
    SET [DATA GROUP].[Type]="G" 
    WHERE [DATA GROUP].[Name] Like "*Graph*"
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Switch` statement is the way to go, but note that separate queries will likely be more efficient, since this query will try to update every row, not only rows matching one of your searches:

```
UPDATE [DATA GROUP]
    SET 
        [DATA GROUP].[Type]= SWITCH(
            [DATA GROUP].[Name] Like "EMI*", "E", 
            [DATA GROUP].[Name] Like "*Graph*", "G", 
            True, "Z"
        )
```

The last row of the `Switch`, `True, [DATA GROUP].[Type]`, makes sure that your column remains unchanged if it doesn't match any of your searches.

To improve efficiency, you can search twice:

```
UPDATE [DATA GROUP]
    SET 
        [DATA GROUP].[Type]= SWITCH(
            [DATA GROUP].[Name] Like "EMI*", "E", 
            [DATA GROUP].[Name] Like "*Graph*", "G", 
            True, [DATA GROUP].[Type]
        )
WHERE
[DATA GROUP].[Name] Like "EMI*" OR
[DATA GROUP].[Name] Like "*Graph*"
```

Comment: What if I want the switch to set to another letter if none of the switches are true?

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you can use the `switch()` function:

```
UPDATE [DATA GROUP]
    SET [Type] = SWITCH([Name] Like "EMI*", "E",
                        [Name] Like "*Graph*", "G",
                        . . .
                       )
    WHERE [Name] Like "EMI*" OR
          [Name] Like "*Graph*" OR
          . . .;
```

Comment: You could've commented on my answer because I confused `switch` and `case`. Anyway, your `WHERE` is assuming those rows are already changed. You're not searching for the `Like` statements like you should. Your current statement will possibly damage the table, because when nothing matches it will null the field.